# FirebaseのGoogle Authでユーザが作成されない

Tags: ios, firebase

お世話になっております。

FirebaseでGoogleアカウントによるユーザ認証をしようとしています。コードはこちらにあります。

https://github.com/ueda-keisuke/CloudMemo

Xcode Version 8.1 (8B62)のSwift 3.0でビルドできるはずです。なお`GoogleService-Info.plist`は入っておりませんが、Firebase側でも特に複雑な作業はしておりません。アプリを作成しバンドルIDを記入してGoogle認証をONにした程度ですので、テストをしていただける場合は`GoogleService-Info.plist`をご用意ください。

### 問題点

FirebaseのGoogle認証が一応成功するが、Firebaseのコンソールで見てみるとユーザが作成されていない。

その結果

```
FIRAuth.auth()?.signIn(with: credential) { (user, error) in
}
```

のuserがnilになる。

### 参考にした情報

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=83EXULT480Q
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/google-signin?hl=ja

前者の動画は後者の公式サイトの情報を参照していますが、Swift 3.0で気をつける点（公式は2.xなのでそのままコピーしても動かない）に配慮してあります。この動画のとおりに作業したつもりです。

動画の場合は問題なく認証に成功し、コンソールにはユーザが追加され、アプリも正しく動作しています。私の手元では同じようにしたつもりでもユーザが追加されず、戻ってきたuser変数もnilになっています。

設定に誤り、あるいは足りない点があれば指摘していただければ幸いです。

よろしくお願いします

Comment: コンソールでGoogle認証の許可は有効ですか？

https://console.firebase.google.com/project/<projectID>/authentication/providers

で 確認できます。

Comment: はい、コンソールの auth の中で Google認証は有効にしてあります。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

自分もAndroidでFirebaseを最近始めてみたばかりなのですが、
コンソール上でGoogle認証を有効にしたあとに `google-services.json` をダウンロードし直さなければいけないという点で一度つまづきました。

iOSの場合は `GoogleService-Info.plist` になると思いますが、
動画の中でその点について触れられていなかったのでそこが気になりました。

見当違いでしたらすみません。

Comment: コメントが遅くなって大変申し訳ありません。GoogleService-Info.plistを削除して再ダウンロード、プロジェクトに配置して実行したところ認証に成功しました。ここがポイントだったようです。ありがとうございます！

Comment: 問題が解決されたのでしたら、回答を承認していただけるとうれしいです